# Remove Parent Style on Carousel

Tags: css

im trying to remove parent style on my sites theme (Shopper WP) on the On Sale Product Grid.  This is because I have added some carousels and wish to keep the same format.  Any idea on how I can force to remove the theme out of it or copy the styles from the other one?  This code is ran by hooks and was able to change some stuff like the limit from 4 to 12.  But I really want to remove the style of this grid.  Let me know if this is enough or if you need more information.  Thanks!!

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'shopper_on_sale_products' ) ) {
/**
 * Display On Sale Products
 * Hooked into the `homepage` action in the homepage template
 *
 * @param array $args the product section args.
 * @since  1.0.0
 * @return void
 */
function shopper_on_sale_products( $args ) {

    if ( shopper_is_woocommerce_activated() ) {

        $args = apply_filters( 'shopper_on_sale_products_args', array(
            'limit'   => 12,
            'columns' => 4,
            'title'   => __( 'On Sale', 'shopper' ),
        ) );

        echo '<section class="shopper-product-section shopper-on-sale-products" aria-label="On Sale Products">';

        do_action( 'shopper_homepage_before_on_sale_products' );

        echo '<h2 class="section-title"><span>' . wp_kses_post( $args['title'] ) . '</span></h2>';

        do_action( 'shopper_homepage_after_on_sale_products_title' );

        echo shopper_do_shortcode( 'sale_products', array(
            'per_page' => intval( $args['limit'] ),
            'columns'  => intval( $args['columns'] ),
        ) );

        do_action( 'shopper_homepage_after_on_sale_products' );

        echo '</section>';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Check the theme files for `wp_enqueue_script()` calls. If you have them, you can [`wp_dequeue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/) with the same handle

Comment: Im new to this, so exploring how to put this code, once i have done it I'll let you know! THanks for the help.